# Pandas: summing unique values in dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following abridged data frame:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/mpl.Bspons.merge.2'

df=df.reset_index()
df.head()

df['billsum'] = df.groupby(['date', 'catcode','disposition', 'id.fec']).bills.transform('sum')
    catcode     date    bills   id.fec  disposition     billsum
0   B1000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     hr2575-113
1   B2000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     hr2575-113
2   B3000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     hr2575-113hr2575-113
3   B6000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     hr2575-113hr2575-113hr2575-113hr2575-113hr2575...
4   B2000   2007    s1782-110   S8WI00026   oppose  s1782-110
```

The problem is that I want to simply sum the column `billsum`instead of outputting all of the bills. When I try to use

```
df['billsum'] = df.groupby(['date', 'catcode','disposition', 'id.fec']).bills.transform('size')
```

I get the following

```
    catcode     date    bills   id.fec  disposition     billsum
0   B1000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     1
1   B2000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     1
2   B3000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     2
3   B6000   2013    hr2575-113  H0IN09070   support     5
4   B2000   2007    s1782-110   S8WI00026   oppose  1

df.to_csv('mpl.billsum', index_col=0)
```

But what I need are the sum of unique values. In my short df above there are no unique values but there are unique values in the larger database. Does someone have an idea on this?

Comment: What would be your expected output in this case?

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, the output does not make sense, as all are updated as 1. If that is the case just use, df['billcount'] = 1.

Comment: I'm going to update my question to provide more detail. Just give me a second.

Comment: are you after `df.groupby('catcode')['billsum'].nunique()` or `df.groupby('catcode')['billsum'].transform('nunique')`?

Comment: @MaxU: Yes! I tried variation of that but came up empty. I'll try applying your suggestion. Maybe there was a small syntax error that I was making. Honestly I'm not sure what the difference is between transform and without `transform`.  But, basically I need a new column that gives me the a count of unique bills.

Comment: I just applied your suggestion. I was not placing  `nunique` inside of the `transform` method; i.e. it works, now! Thanks again.

Comment: Could you make the question title a bit more descriptive? (I.e., include the keywords 'pandas' and 'DataFrame' in the title). From the title and question, it's not clear what kind of object `df` is.